# Loop Tools not in Add-On menu in 2.78

Tags: add-on

can anyone help me out with this? I am trying to find the loop tools (i'm using 2.78) and it's nowhere to be found in the add-on menu in user preferences. is anyone else having this problem or is it somewhere else? 
just don't feel like downloading it if it's already here somewhere...
i tried typing it in to find it but nothing came up!

Thanks!

Comment: Type *loop* in addons search field, it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Im using 2.78c and it is in my add-ons list.

Maybe somehow it got deleted.

[image]